# Excluir campos al hacer el sort - vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Estoy trabajando en el siguiente formulario con vuex (imagen). Al momento de Editar, cuando agrego campos, estos se ordenan, por los mas nuevos,, toman la ultma posicion.
Necesito modificarlo, para que al ordenar estos campos(items), ciertos campos específicos("inicio  de ruta" y "fin de ruta" ) no se muevan,, es decir, que permanezcan siempre al ultimo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi funcion que maneja el orden

```
handleFieldSort() {
      this.entity.milestone_detail = this.entity.milestone_detail
          .map((item, index) => {
            console.log("acá item", item)
            console.log("acá index", index)

            let element = {
              ...item,
              sort: index + 1,
            }

            if (item._destroy) element.sort = index + 999

            return element
          });
    },
```

Así estan definidos en la base de datos:
los campos Inicio y fin de ruta tienen el sort en 99, pensando en que se queden siempreal final.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estaba pensando en evaluarlos en un if y que solo ordene los menores a 99 o bien. los que tuvieran el dynamic_cols en null. Pero no me va bien. Estoy partiendo con Vue.

Espero me puedan orientar un poco.

Comment: vue es js.. no es vue.. vuex es el store de vue.. no es otra cosa, que js...  no entiendo que tiene que ver la base de datos con tu problema...

Comment: Simplemente para ver con que columnas podria hacer la condicion contra el sort.

Comment: Entonces no termino de entender tu problema. ahi estas creando un nuevo array, no ordenando... tu problema es que no sabes como hacer el orden? habria que ver como esta definido item entonces...

Comment: Hola @gbianchi. Si lo ordena. Lo que necesito hacer es: que de esos items a ordenar, excluya los que tienen el sort 99, ya que cuando actualizo me cambia el sort. por ej. De 99 lo deja en 1, entonces me queda al principio.